# http error 500 not redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a custom page for handle server errors like `404` and `500` or etc. so:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
```

`404` works good but error `500` not redirect to custom page. i made error by removing a `semicolon` and still get browser error:

> **This page isn’t working**
>
> example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

Googled but couldn't find anything to solve this.

Comment: Chrome hijacks 404/500 errors under a certain byte size, IIRC (on the assumption that it's not showing a useful page and that the user will benefit more from Chrome's built-in message). What does your `500.php` file contain? If you view source, are its contents there? Try adding a few paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: @ceejayoz it contains `background-image` , view source is empty, blank. **Edit:** added some text but still same.

Comment: "it contains background-image" What, and nothing else?

Comment: nothing else, it shows a graphic related image, i don't want user see browser error page, instead want to show this image.

Comment: How much text did you have? The 404 handling needs at least 512 bytes. I'd bet the 500 is similar.

Comment: for example i added 4570 chars with 23 line 4.5 kb still same @ceejayoz